# How to pass data in an innerhtml in javascript to another page and store in mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

From this index.js file, when the user finish playing the game,the output is display at the innerhtml which I not sure how to retrieve the level , clicks and efficiency variables that store in this file and display on another php page so that I can store in mysql database?

index.php file

```
<p id="game-info">&nbsp;</p>

<ul id="levels">
    <li class="selected"><a href="javascript:" level="0">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="1">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="2">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="3">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="4">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="5">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="6">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="7">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="8">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" level="9">10</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="playfield-wrapper">&nbsp;<div class="win-text">Win</div></div>

      <button id="score">Submit</button>
      <form  id='postscoreform' action="memorygamescore.php" method="get">
        <input type='hidden' value='0' id="postscore" name='score' />
      </form>
```

index.js file

```
var MemoryGame = function (evt) {
        "use strict";
        var lvlNum      = 0,
            info        = document.getElementById('game-info'),
            lvlCtrls    = document.getElementById('levels'),
            lvls        = [
                {'rows': 3, 'cols': 4, 'matches': 2},
                {'rows': 4, 'cols': 4, 'matches': 2},
                {'rows': 4, 'cols': 5, 'matches': 2},
                {'rows': 3, 'cols': 4, 'matches': 3},
                {'rows': 3, 'cols': 5, 'matches': 3},
                {'rows': 3, 'cols': 6, 'matches': 3},
                {'rows': 4, 'cols': 4, 'matches': 4},
                {'rows': 4, 'cols': 5, 'matches': 4},
                {'rows': 4, 'cols': 6, 'matches': 4},
                {'rows': 5, 'cols': 6, 'matches': 5}
            ],
            lastBtn     = lvlCtrls.childNodes[1],
            btn         = null,
            lvl         = lvls[lvlNum],
            currentLvl  = null,
            start       = function () {
                currentLvl = new Level(evt, lvl.rows, lvl.cols, lvl.matches);
                currentLvl.onwin = function (clicks, prc) {
                    info.innerHTML = 'You\'ve found all matches in <strong>' + clicks + '</strong> clicks with <strong>' + prc + '%</strong> efficiency';
                };

                info.innerHTML = 'Click the cards to reveal <strong>' + lvl.matches + '</strong> matches';

                //Retrieve game points
                alert('a');
                $('#score').click(function() {
                    alert('b');
                $('#postscore').val(clicks);
                $('#postscoreform').submit();
                      });
            };

        start();

        evt.attach('mousedown', lvlCtrls, function (e, src) {
            if (src.tagName === 'A') {
                btn = src.parentNode;

                lastBtn.className = '';
                btn.className = 'selected';

                lastBtn = btn;

                lvlNum = src.getAttribute('level');
                lvl = lvls[lvlNum];
                start();
            }
        });
    };
```

Somebody please help me!!

Comment: what is the output of `$_GET['score']` ?

Comment: i did the form in the html file was trying to get the number of clicks from .js file but nothing was retrieved from the output.

Comment: Could you narrow down the code you posted to the relevant parts?

Comment: `$('#postscore').val(click);` - `click` is undefined in that scope

Comment: I created an form which contains a button in which I tried to retrieve it from  this file but it wasnt working at all